# Get shortinformation using GoogleMaps JS API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get informations about a place using the GoogleMaps JS API (v3). At this point everything is working fine using the code below.

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;
function initialize() {
    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(0.00,0.00);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: loc,
        zoom: 15
    });
        
    var request = {
        location: loc,
        radius: "100",
        query: "somequery"
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.textSearch(request, callback);
}
        
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            console.log(place);
        }
    }
}
  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

Of course `0.00` and `"somequery"` are placeholders.
When I'm using GoogleMaps Places, clicking on a place will show me the exact same result, that is stored in my results-Object in the callback-Method.

The only thing I dont get is the short information text (most of the time, if not everytime, it is an extracted wikipedia article). I can't find any reference regarding this in the Google Maps JS API documentation.

Is there any way to get this short text?

---

#### Solved

The solution is as easy as the abc... use the wikipedia API! mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: Can you share an example of the response that gives you the wiki articles, what property name in the response is used?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to get the info in the response. It seems (printing the object proves that), that there is no field for this short information. Have a look at the Empire State Building https://www.google.de/maps/place/Empire+State+Building/@40.74844,-73.985664,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c259a9b3117469:0xd134e199a405a163 On the left site you will see three cards. The last one is the shortinformation I'm reffering to.

Comment: results should be an array of PlaceResult objects - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult. So you should see the properties on your place variable as per that doc link

Comment: Not each feature you'll see on maps.google.com is implemented in the API's

Comment: Well as per that link to the docs I referenced, I don't think you can get that information, seems something that Google keep for themselves.

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: Thats all I need, thanks!